# Can't get the simplest problem matcher to report any problem

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-problem-matcher

I've been googling for hours, simplifying to the dumbest vs code project:

[image]

The task runs:
[image]

Output is empty:
[image]

And no problem is reported.

What am I missing?

[Edit]

As requested in the comments, here I echo an actual error message, copied from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher:

echo helloWorld.c:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prinft’

I copied the example problem matcher from the same link. Still doesn't show anything. For some reason the terminal output has some line feeds.

[image]

[Edit 2]
Ok, thanks to help from rioV8 and Yassin Hajaj, I figured it out. That was a frustrating way to learn how problem matchers work. My lack of experience with regexp didn't help.

Turns out "shell" defaults to PowerShell, which has an echo command displaying each token to a new line. I finally got it to be one line with some escaping trickery:

```
"command": "echo \\\"dummy.cpp:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prinft’\\\""
```

Also the file, line, and message properties are mandatory.

So here's a working example:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            // by default the command appears in the terminal so 2 lines will actually be matched
            "command": "echo \\\"dummy.cpp:5:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prinft’\\\"",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you don't define capture groups

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for your reply, I'm sorry I must be stupid, could you give an example of a regexp that would report hello as a problem here?

Comment: I tried with `"(.*)"` and it doesn't work either :(

Comment: what happens if you echo something looking like an error line and a problem matcher that matches that line

Comment: Your example uses capture groups and also start/end of string. Can you try the following? `^(.*)$`

Comment: @YassinHajaj, Just tried `"regexp": "^(.*)$"` but it didn't work either. I wonder if there's something wrong with my vscode installation

Comment: I'll check locally if I can reproduce it

Comment: @YassinHajaj thanks, that'd be appreciated

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57 I find this in the docs _Note that the file, line, and message properties are mandatory._

Comment: your output is not on 1 line, write a small python script that prints this line and call this script, also use a different owner

Comment: Ok, You've figured this out. I've edited the question. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.